# How to find the highest N values in each group in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to use a formula to find the highest N values in each group in a Google Spread Sheets.

I tried this formula from [infoinspired.com](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-the-highest-n-values-in-each-group/) (credit to Prashanth):

> =ArrayFormula(QUERY({SORT(A2:B;1;true;2;false);IFERROR(row(A2:A)-match(query(SORT(A2:B;1;true;2;false);"Select Col1");query(SORT(A2:B;1;true;2;false);"Select Col1");0))};"Select Col1,Col2 where Col3<3"))

But all it return is an Array_Literal error:
[image: error]

This is what I expect:
[image: expected]

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please do not add answers as edits to questions. Use space below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a comma, not a semi colon before IFERROR. It's creating two columns, one twice larger than the other instead of three columns ;)

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({SORT(A2:B,1,true,2,false),IFERROR(row(A2:A)-match(query(SORT(A2:B,1,true,2,false),"Select Col1"),query(SORT(A2:B,1,true,2,false),"Select Col1"),0))},"Select Col1,Col2 where Col3<3"))
```

[image]

Comment: When i change ";" to "," before "IFERROR", it return #ERROR! instead :(

Comment: That's odd, just by modifying it it works perfectly. I'll copy the formula in my answer so you can try it:

Comment: Got it! I changed the country to Canada (Anglais) to make it working using comma, then I returned to Canada (Français) to have it converted. So "," before IFERROR converted to "\".

Comment: You are right! I actually changed the locale in general so I wouldn't have that problem when working in places like these, sorry I didn't observed that in your formula!

Answer (score 0):

alternative formula:

`=QUERY(SORT({{A2:B}\MAP(A2:A;B2:B;lambda(ax;bx;IFERROR(Rank(bx;Filter(B$2:$B;A$2:$A=ax);0);IFERROR(1/0))))};1;0;3;1);"Select Col1, Col2 Where Col3<3")`

-

[image]